# Post Condition failed on Migration between Azure Servers

Tags: azure, scaling, migration

We are trying to migrate our application from Azure US servers to EU Servers. We just copied all the files of Website folder (or wwwroot folder) from US server to EU server.

Our Production CM environment worked without any effort but we are facing issues while loading the Prod CD environment. It is throwing the following error:

[image]

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Post condition failed
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Post condition failed]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ResultNotNull(T result, String message) +85
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name) +86
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabases() +121
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.Initialize() +96
   (Object , Object[] ) +120
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   (Object , Object[] ) +71
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +291
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +673
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +580
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +165
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +267
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +341

[HttpException (0x80004005): Post condition failed]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +688
```

I compared both the CD environment file system (the working US Azure and the new EU Azure) and couldn't find any difference.

Please let me know why exactly this error is showing up.

Comment: Can your CD get to the databases?

Comment: Please include the stack trace information as text, not image. Search Engines need something to work with.

Comment: Hello @MarkCassidy - I have included the text, please do the needful.